# Build Qt projects using static build

Tags: qt

I have created a program in Qt using Qt Creator. When I open it, the message appears "The program can't start because Qt5Cored.dll and Qt5widgetsx.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

Answer (score 0):

copy required libraries from you Qt installation to the directory of executable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you really got a static compiled version of Qt? and are you statically compiling your project?... if so your output executable will be around 30-40mb.... and it won't be asking you for dlls.

However it looks like you have a dynamically linked output, in which case you need to find all the DLLs that your projects uses. You can get these from the folder:

`<installpath>\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin` for example (different if you use linux / msvc)

Keep running the program and grab each dll it complains about... or use somthing like dependency walker (a free executable you can find online) to help determine which DLLs you need.

You probably need (For windows, using mingw):

- Qt5Widgets.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- libwinpthread-1.dll
- libstdc++-6.dll
- libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

Or the debug version in your case which end in "d" e.g.: Qt5Core.dll (release), Qt5Cored.dll (debug). Note versions may be different for your installation version. Copy these files next to your executable. OR include `<installpath>\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\bin` in your path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the required dlls

> C:\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\bin\

to your project. https://forum.qt.io/topic/50705/solved-qt3d-executable-error-qt5cored-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer/2 should solve your problem.